# Abundant vs Non-Abundant Matrices

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I've been told to write a program which will read a file of three arrays, each of which are 5 x 6 in size and contain many 0's and non-zero numbers. Then I am to create an array with an undefined number of rows, but 3 columns, which dictate where the non-zero numbers are located. In the first column is the row-index, and in the second column is the column-index. The third column contains the actual non-zero number itself.

It is a very roundabout program. But I believe the main issue I have is this--

1. When two non-zero numbers are in the same row, it's somehow impossible for me to print out the same row index in the new matrix for both numbers. I tried setting the row-index to a and then the row-index to a separate counter for rows, but it still messes up and increments the rows one by one. At the moment, my mind has drawn a blank.

The only way my code will print is if I set my rind to 1 instead of 0. But this throws the entire program off; I've changed it to 1 to illustrate my problem more clearly

Perhaps this is a little too much to ask for on a school assignment, I apologize. If this post somehow betrays the rules I will remove it promptly.

Thank you to anyone who is willing to spare this a glance.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog465h {


    static Scanner inFile = null;

    public static void main(String[]args) {



        try {

            // create scanner to read file
            inFile = new Scanner(new File ("prog465h.dat"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(0);
        }





        while(inFile.hasNext()) {

            int rows = inFile.nextInt();
            int columns = inFile.nextInt();

            int rind = 1;

            int cr = 0; // count rows
            int cc = 0; // count zeroes

            int[][] first = new int[rows][columns];


            for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {

                    // catch the next

                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {

                    first[a][b] = inFile.nextInt();

                }

            }

            for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {


                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {

                    System.out.print(first[a][b] + " ");
                    if (first[a][b] != 0) {

                        rind++;

                    }

                }

                System.out.println(" ");

            }


            System.out.println("COUNTS ARE BELOW:");

            int[][] mod = new int [rind][3];    // new array based on non-zeroes

            for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {
                    cc = 0;

                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {

                        if (first[a][b] == 0) { // if there is a 0 increase number of columns counted

                            cc++;

                        } else {    // if not--

                            mod[cr][2] = first[a][b];   // then make this nonzero number the last column of x row of mod.
                                                        // x row depends on...?
                                                        // the number of counted rows?
                            mod[cr][0] = (a+1); // put the number of rows counted for this number
                            mod[cr][1] = (cc+1); // put the number of 0's (aka columns) counted for this number

                            cc = 0;

                        }




                }

                cr++;



            }

            for (int a = 0; a < mod.length; a++) {


                for (int b = 0; b < mod[a].length; b++) {

                    System.out.print(mod[a][b] + " ");


                }

                System.out.println(" ");

            }

            System.out.println("\n **** ALL DONE **** \n");

        }



    }

}
```

My output: (Notice how for the first matrix, it prints three 0's. This shouldn't be happening, it should just skip the row entirely.)

```
0 0 7 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 -8 0  
0 0 0 0 0 0  
2 0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0 0  
COUNTS ARE BELOW:
1 3 7  
2 5 -8  
0 0 0  
4 1 2  

 **** ALL DONE **** 

0 2 0 3 0 1  
8 0 4 0 1 0  
0 3 0 1 0 -7  
5 0 9 0 6 0  
0 2 0 -1 0 7  
COUNTS ARE BELOW:
1 2 1  
2 2 1  
3 2 -7  
4 2 6  
5 2 7  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  

 **** ALL DONE **** 

0 0 1 0 0 2  
3 0 0 4 0 0  
0 0 5 0 0 6  
7 0 0 8 0 0  
0 0 9 0 0 1  
COUNTS ARE BELOW:
1 3 2  
2 3 4  
3 3 6  
4 3 8  
5 3 1  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0  

 **** ALL DONE ****
```

Sample Output (What the output should be):

```
Original Matrix
   0   0   7   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0  -8   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
   2   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1    3    7
    2    5   -8
    4    1    2
The Original Matrix is Sparse


Original Matrix
   0   2   0   3   0   1
   8   0   4   0   1   0
   0   3   0   1   0  -7
   5   0   9   0   6   0
   0   2   0  -1   0   7
The Original Matrix is Abundant


Original Matrix
   0   0   1   0   0   2
   3   0   0   4   0   0
   0   0   5   0   0   6
   7   0   0   8   0   0
   0   0   9   0   0   1
    1    3    1
    1    6    2
    2    1    3
    2    4    4
    3    3    5
    0    0    9
    4    1    7
    4    4    8
    5    3    9
    5    6    1
The Original Matrix and the Sparse Matrix
are Equally Efficient
```

The file:

```
5
6
0 0 7 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 -8 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
5
6
0 2 0 3 0 1
8 0 4 0 1 0
0 3 0 1 0 -7
5 0 9 0 6 0
0 2 0 -1 0 7
5
6
0 0 1 0 0 2
3 0 0 4 0 0
0 0 5 0 0 6
7 0 0 8 0 0
0 0 9 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your up front honesty about this being homework is appreciated. In general, I don't think you'll have a problem getting assistance if you post questions like this. You've clearly attempted the problem and are incredibly close to getting it working.

I've had a look and it seems you just need to move the line `cr++;` up a little bit. Move it up a couple of lines so that it is within the inner for loop (so it executes immediately after the line `cc = 0;` Also, make sure that you initialise `int rind = 0;` (and not 1). You'll also need to change `cc = 0;` to `cc++;`.

When I ran it, it produced the sample output you posted in your question.

Just an observation, but you could also tidy up your code a little by condensing your 2 for loops into one:

```
           for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {
                // catch the next
                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {
                    first[a][b] = inFile.nextInt();
                }
            }

            for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(first[a][b] + " ");
                    if (first[a][b] != 0) {
                        rind++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
```

Could become:

```
         for (int a = 0; a < first.length; a++) {
                // catch the next
                for (int b = 0; b < first[a].length; b++) {
                    first[a][b] = inFile.nextInt();
                    System.out.print(first[a][b] + " ");
                    if (first[a][b] != 0) {
                        rind++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It works perfectly now. I'll also go back and rectify my for-loop as well. Thanks for going so far and giving me good advice. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Nikolas Glad to help. I did notice that on the last matrix the output was wrong. You need to change `cc=0;` to `cc++` within the inner loop. I've edited my answer.